# Angular2 Observable not triggering rerendering

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, behaviorsubject

TLDR: Observable object doesn't trigger component rerendering until an action is made by the user (click on a button for example).

I'm updating an observable backed by a BehaviorSubject contained inside a service that is injected inside my component.

In my component, I'm using a simple `*ngIf="myObservable$ | async"` to display a div.

I managed to replicate 2 situations, one working and one that doesn't but I can't understand what's the difference:

```
//CASE 1
this._mySubject$.next(true); //THIS DOES TRIGGER RERENDERING
//CASE 2
this.http.get(url)
.map( res => res.json() )
.subscribe( body => {
    this._mySubject$.next(true); //THIS DOESN'T TRIGGER RERENDERING UNTIL AN ACTION IS MADE
});
```

Comment: How is the whole stream triggered? And what version of angular2 are you using? - You can probably solve your issue by wrapping the `.next(true)` in an `ngZone.run(...)` - however this should not be necessary with a simple rest-call, so my current guess is that your rest-call is somehow wrapped inside some other async/external trigger

Comment: I'm using Angular 2.1.0.
My component which is already subscribed to the observable calls the service function, which makes the simple http call (not wrapped in anything).

Comment: Any particular reason for using the `subcribe()` block to call `.next()`? Subscribe blocks shouldn't be used to generate side effects. Only the final consumer(s) of the observable should subscribe.

Comment: You're right. I need to subscribe here just to trigger the http call otherwise. In my original code I do the `.next()` on another `map` then I transform the observable into a Promise using `.toPromise()`. But this is not the issue unfortunately.


Also for those interested, I'm using this state management architecture: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do side effects try to do it in the **do** operator

```
this.http.get(url)
.map( res => res.json() )
.do( () => this._mySubject$.next(true))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: I also tried this way and it still doesn't trigger rerendering.

Comment: @Yanis26 At the template are you doing `*ngIf="_mySubject$ | async"` ??

Comment: I'm using the observable of my BehaviorSubject in my template ( `_.mySubject$.asObservable()` ) so the component can't mutate the data.

What's weird is that I'm doing this with 3 other BehaviorSubject/Observable with the same setup: http request -> pushing data received into my subject -> the component updates itself.

Only this one doesn't work and it's quite frustrating since everything else is done exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea to subscribe to the behavior subject in the ngOnInit method and set a property to use in the ngIf. Since the actual object is not a new object just a new emission from the behavior subject it is probably not triggering Angular's change detection. It seems to play best with immutable objects.